# SFML C++ столкновения

Tags: c++, sfml

Я пишу для практики небольшую физическую модель (*если это можно таковым назвать*). У меня есть квадраты, создаваемые на левую кнопку мыши, которые могут пока что только падать. Мне нужно определять столкновения и понимать с какой стороны это было. Но дело в том, что с каждым новым квадратом программа заметно замедляется. Все из-за того, что я проверяю каждый квадрат на столкновение со всеми существующими квадратами. Как я могу проверять на столкновения более эффективным способом?

Не судите строго, впервые с таким сталкиваюсь и впервые задаю вопрос тут

https://github.com/Cominta/hitbox-prototype
Тут есть код (там уже не прописана функция определения столкновения с другими квадратами, но я там просто проверял через intersects). Проблемы с замедлением программы присутствуют и там

Comment: Ответ присутствует в комментарии к вопросу.